# Algorithms with different complexity

Tags: algorithm, optimization, complexity-theory

Can the complexity of an algorithm be at the time in O(n^2) and in O(n logn)? i am sure about this one. But what about in Ω(n^2) and in O(n logn), also and in Θ(n^2) and in Ω(n logn). Thanks

Comment: I think you are missing an important letter when you say `and in (n logn)`- did you mean to put an `O`, an `Ω`, or a `Θ` there before the parentheses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Big-O notation refers only to the upper bound. Thus, if it is in `O(n log n)`, it is necessarily in `O(n^2)` (since `n^2` grows faster than `n log n`).
2. No, it cannot be in both `Ω(n^2)` and in `O(n log n)`. That would mean "upper bounded by `n log n` and lower bounded by `n^2`, which is impossible.
3. `Θ(n^2)` means it is bounded both above and below by `n^2`, which necessarily means it is bounded below by `Ω(n log n)`.

Comment: thanks, but what about in Ω(n^2) and in O(n logn) it seems correct.